# How to set Electron application icon in Windows "Add or Remove Programs"/"Apps"?

Tags: electron

I'm working on an Electron app (for Mac and Windows) and I need it to have a custom icon.  I've been able to get the custom icon to show properly in most circumstances except in the Windows "Add or Remove Programs"/"Apps" section.  In that spot, the icon is still a generic Electron icon.  See the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to get the icon to display properly in that context as well? Thanks so much.